# JPA - Entity with One-to-many - relationship returns no data

Tags: java, jpa, entity, one-to-many, openjpa

I am using the ReverseMappingTool to create JPA-Sources for an existing database-scheme.

It works fine, with one exception: After the creation, when calling the get-Methods data from One-to-many relationships are not loaded.

The JPA files look like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="myScheme", name="ORDER")
@IdClass(org.company.OrderId.class)
public class Order {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=org.company.Orderposition.class, mappedBy="order", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Set orderpositions = new HashSet();

public Set getOrderpositions() {
    return bestellpositions;
}

public void setOrderpositions(Set orderpositions) {
    this.orderpositions = orderpositions;
}

public Set getDependantPositions() {
    if (getOrderpositions() != null) {
        return getOrderpositions();
    }
}
```

and...

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="myScheme", name="ORDERPOSITION")
@IdClass(org.company.Orderposition.Id.class)
public class Orderposition {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name="intid_strbestellung", nullable=false)
    private Order order;

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }
```

The method "getDependantPositions()" is just an example of a method I have placed inside the JPA class. It is necessary to do that, so lets take it as given. The point is, that calling getOrderpositions() does not return any data though the database contains lot of entries for this object. The mapping tool has not added any FetchType for @OneToMany-Relationships... so I guess its LAZY and calling getOrderpositions() should return all relevant values.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

P.S.: Thats the way I calling thr ReverseMappingTool:

```
Options opts = new Options();
        // Output directory - All generated code and metadata will be written to the directory at this path
        opts.setProperty("directory", PATH_SOURCEGENERATION);
        // True to generate JPA annotations in generated java classes. 
        opts.setProperty("annotations", true);
        // disable orm.xml generation
        opts.setProperty("metadata", "none");
        // The full class name of a org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseCustomizer customization plugin
        opts.setProperty("customizerClass", JPAPropertiesReverseCustomizer.name);
        // Create built-in application identity classes if possible
        opts.setProperty("useBuiltinIdentityClass", false);
        // Avoid creating classes for many-many join tables
        opts.setProperty("primaryKeyOnJoin", true);
        // Prevent the creation of inverse 1-many/1-1 relations for every many-1/1-1 relation detected
        opts.setProperty("inverseRelations", true);

        opts.setProperty("innerIdentityClasses", true);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Please fix the issues so that we can concentrate on actual code. Moreover, testing if toManyAssociation is null will always return false. The set will be empty if there's no associated entity, and not null. Please show us the code that doesn't work as intended, and the relevant data in your tables. Finally, why don't you use generic types?

Comment: Hi JB Nizet... I changed the code a bit to poste it here.. changing name from german to english, etc. The files compile fine. the getDependantPositions() Method is also an example... It is generally calling the Get-Method of the OnetoMany-attribute...   I will add the generics.. thanks for that info...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure your logs so that you see what queries are sent to DB. Then you will be able to check: 1. what query goes to DB when `Order` is loaded and 2. what (and if any) query goes to DB when you get contents of Set returned by `getOrderpositions()`. Note that you have to **access the content of the Set**, just calling the getter will not invoke any DB query in lazy-loaded association.

Comment: Hi Adam, I called the getter and tried to access the elements by calling the iterator of the set, etc. But it keeps to be empty. Or do I have to work with the attribute itself?

Comment: @Randbedingung You need to iterate over the Set. What about the logs? If configured properly they show the exact query ORM is sending to DB and verify if JPA is doing what you expect.

Comment: Sooooo... It finally works.  I set the debug modus by changing "showSql" attribute in OpenJpaVendorAdapter (Spring). It had no effect, the sql queries had not been displayed. Then i recognized that i instantiated the JPA class with my own classloader. I was able to instantiate it, but not has "managed" JPa class. My mistake was not to load the class via LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.. changed that and everything was fine :-) Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hi @Randbedingung, could you please elaborate a bit more your answer, I am having this same issue, and have not find a way to tackle it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17125641/866390 here's the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default OneToMany Fetch Type is Lazy. If you want to load this data you have to use the JPQL statement

```
SELECT t FROM TABLE t JOIN FETCH t.joinedTable
```

Or you specify FetchType.EAGER in the OneToMany mapping everywhere. But this will mean that the relation is always loaded.

See also for example: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.1.0/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_fetch_joins

Sebastian

Comment: Hi Sebastian... I thought that LAZY - fetchtype means: load when first called.. e.g. getOrderPositions(). Do I really have to use JPQL to get the data?

Comment: You are right, my advice is connected to when you want to force loading. However you might force it to see if orderpositions are loaded at all or if there is a mapping issue.